# Creating processes that contains infinite loop in python

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing

I want to create processes without waiting for other processes finish which they can't because they are in an infinite loop.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def child_function(param1, param2):
    print(str(param1 * param2))
    while True:
        print("doing some stuff")
        time.sleep(3)


def main_function():
    print("Initializing some things.")
    for _ in range(10):
        Process(target=child_function(3, 5)).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_function()
```

This code only starts one process and waits for it to finish. How can I do this?

Edit: Comment answer works fine and the answer below also works fine but for creating thread. Thank you everyone.

Comment: The code *doesn't start any subprocesses*. You try to pass `child_function(3, 5)` to the `target` argument of `Process`, so *this calls the function and you go into the function and execute the infinite loop*. You are supposed to provide **the function**

Comment: So here, just use `Process(target=child_function, args=(3, 5))`

Comment: thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga it works like a charm.

Comment: "This code only starts one process and waits for it to finish."  actually nowhere does your code wait for the child process to finish.. for that you need to save a reference to the process object, and call `join()` on it after you `start()` it. Technically it works because python tries to clean-up the existing child processes on exit, but this is kinda like relying on the OS to close your file handles for you when a process exits. It's more reliable to do it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Python module [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

```
import time
import threading

def child_function(param1, param2):
    print(str(param1 * param2))
    while True:
        print("doing some stuff")
        time.sleep(3)

def main_function():
    print("Initializing some things.")
    for _ in range(10):
        x = threading.Thread(target=child_function, args=(3,5, ))
        x.start()

main_function()
```

**Explanation:** as already mentioned in the **comments,** notice that we are passing the function as opposed to calling it via the thread constructor, Also you can compare [Threading vs Multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python) and use whichever best suits the project.

Comment: Why switch out `multiprocessing` for `threading` when OP didn't ask to? also you corrected OP's actual problem without calling out what it was. You should edit your answer to highlight the need to pass the function instead of calling it in the thread/process constructor.

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron for the Input, I have added some explanation and additional resources for the OP.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this, if you can edit it and I can remove the downvote

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga what needs to be edited?

Comment: @Agnij just edit *something* or else I can't revert my downvote

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay, Done!